# Linux string manipulation to make two parameters from one

Tags: bash, sed, xargs, rhel8, one-liner

I'm receiving a list of operating systems, one per line, such as:

```
alpine/3.13
alpine/edge
alt/Sisyphus
alt/p9
apertis/v2019.5
```

I need to massage each line into two parameters to yield:

```
lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13
lxc launch images:alpine/edge alpine-edge
lxc launch images:alt/Sisyphus alt-Sisyphus
lxc launch images:alt/p9 alt-p9
lxc launch images:apertis/v2019.5 apertis-v2019-5
```

and then run those commands.  Note the second parameter has had everything non-alphanumeric switched to hyphens.  I came up with the following:

```
echo alpine/3.13 | sed 'h;s#[/.]#-#g;x;G;s/\n/ /' | xargs -ti lxc launch images:{}
```

Unfortunately, although the command that xargs runs looks correct, instead of passing two arguments to lxc, xargs passes the entire thing as a single argument, so lxc tries to download an image named "alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13", instead of downloading the image named alpine/3.13 and using it to create a container named alpine-3-13.

Is there a way to pass lxc two separate arguments?

Example output:

```
# echo alpine/3.13 | sed 'h;s#[/.]#-#g;x;G;s/\n/ /' | xargs -ti lxc launch images:{}
lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13
Creating the instance
Error: Failed instance creation: The requested image couldn't be found
# lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13
Creating alpine-3-13
Starting alpine-3-13
<works correctly>
```

Complete (working) final command based on below input from KamilCuk and markp-fuso:

```
lxc image list images: | grep -v cloud | grep -Po '^\| \K[^ ]+(?=.+x86_64.+CONTAINER)' | sed 'h;s#[^[:alnum:]]#-#g;x;G;s/\n/ /;s/^ */images:/' | xargs -n2 lxc launch
```

Comment: `that runs looks correct` how can that `sed` "look" correct?

Comment: The t param to xargs tells it to output what it is about to run.  It says it is going to run "lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13", which works fine when pasted to a bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks over-complicated - you do not need to use hold space at all. For remembering stuff from pattern and shuffling it use backreferences. Just:

```
echo alpine/3.13 | sed 's#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#lxc launch images:& \1-\2#'
```

You could run like:

```
echo alpine/3.13 | sed 's#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#images:& \1-\2#' | xargs -n2 lxc launch
```

or just:

```
eval "$(echo alpine/3.13 | sed 's#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#lxc launch images:& \1-\2#')"
```

But I would go with proper code anyway.

```
func() {
  arg=${1//\//-}
  lxc launch images:"$1" "$arg"
}
while IFS= read -r line; do
     func "$line"
done <<EOF
alpine/3.13 
EOF
```

or with same function:

```
export -f func
echo alpine/3.13 | xargs -d '\n' -n1 bash -c 'func "$@"' _
```

> Is there a way to pass lxc two separate arguments?

Yes, but `xargs` has to know what to do with it. You can't "glue" two arguments with something in xargs - `-i` grabs only one argument. You could glue the `images:` in sed and then pass it, using your sed hold space shuffling, it's:

```
echo alpine/3.13 | sed 'h;s#[/.]#-#g;x;G;s/\n/ /;s/^ */images:/' | xargs -t -n2 lxc launch
```

but I see no value in `xargs` here at all anyway.

Comment: Your first example displays a command but doesn't actually run it. Most of your examples do not replace all the non-alphanumeric characters.in the second parameter (currently that is only slashes and periods). Your last example does appear to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OP's examples start with `echo <operating_system_string>` which I'm going to assume implies  the input file (full of `<operating_systen_string>'s`) is being passed through some sort of loop, and upon each pass through the loop a variable is being assigned the current `<operating_system_string>`.

Key point here is that a variable is going to be used to hold the current `<operating_system_string>`.

I'm wondering if OP can use parameter substitution to accomplish the desired task, eg:

```
$ osname='alpine/3.13'
$ echo "${osname//[^[:alnum:]]/-}"     # replace all non-alphanumerics with a '-'
alpine-3-13
```

So making the `lxc` call would look like:

```
$ echo lxc launch images:"${osname}" "${osname//[^[:alnum:]]/-}"
lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13

$ lxc launch images:"${osname}" "${osname//[^[:alnum:]]/-}"
```

---

Taking a run at the list of OS names ...

Input file:

```
$ cat oslist
alpine/3.13
alpine/edge
alt/Sisyphus
alt/p9
apertis/v2019.5
```

Running the file through a `while` loop:

```
while read -r osname
do
    echo lxc launch images:"${osname}" "${osname//[^[:alnum:]]/-}"
done < oslist
```

Which generates:

```
lxc launch images:alpine/3.13 alpine-3-13
lxc launch images:alpine/edge alpine-edge
lxc launch images:alt/Sisyphus alt-Sisyphus
lxc launch images:alt/p9 alt-p9
lxc launch images:apertis/v2019.5 apertis-v2019-5
```

Once OP is satisfied with the results the `echo` could be removed to instead invoke the `lxc` call on each pass through the loop.